# Como fazer soma de campos entre tabelas diferentes no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

COMPRA

```
id_compra  
desc_compra  
valortotal_compra  
data_compra  
id_colaborador
```

COMPRAPROD

```
id_compraprod  
id_compra  
id_produto  
qtd_compraprod  
valorunit_compraprod  
valortotal_compraprod
```

COMPRAMAT

```
id_compramat  
id_compra  
id_material  
qtd_compramat  
valorunit_compramat  
valortotal_compramat
```

Gostaria que o campo ***valortotal_compra***, da tabela COMPRA, receba a soma dos valores ***valortotal_compramat*** e ***valortotal_compraprod***, das tabelas COMPRAMAT e COMPRAPROD, respectivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce tem que pegar os pontos em comum entre as tabelas, as relações. A grosso modo seria isso:

```
update compra set valortotal_compra = (
(select sum(valortotal_compraprod) from COMPRAPROD where id_compra  = :idcompra)+
(select sum(valortotal_compramat)  from COMPRAMAT where id_compra  = :idcompra)
)
where id_compra  = :id_compra
```

você faz dois subselect e o update para receber

Answer (score 1):

Visto que só há um campo que é comum a todas as tabelas, `id_compra`, então você pode fazer um `NATURAL JOIN`, pois ele utilizará este campo para fazer o join. Caso você não queira atualizar a tabela inteira de uma vez, então você pode adicionar uma cláusula `WHERE` ou substituir o `NATURAL JOIN` por `INNER JOIN` com cláusula `ON`.

```
UPDATE        compra     c
NATURAL JOIN  compraprod p
NATURAL JOIN  compramat  m
SET c.valortotal_compra = ( SUM(p.valortotal_compraprod) + SUM(m.valortotal_compramat) )
```